# How to [window setAspectRatio:size] to a x,y+92 format

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, aspect-ratio

I'm creating an OS X application, and I have a video player in a web view that covers 100% of the height and width of a window The player has 16:9 format, plus 92px in height for ads and player controls.

So I want to set the window's aspect ratio, so that when a user resizes the window, the aspect ratio of the video is maintained, *including* the extra 92px in height.

at the moment, I used;

```
[window setAspectRatio:window.frame.size];
```

But obviously that also proportionally adds to the 92px constant and thus alters the video player's aspect ratio.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple as setting an object to be the window's delegate and implementing [`windowWillResize:toSize:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008202-CH1-SW9). The window passes its proposed new size; the delegate can return a different size and the window will use that.

```
- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize 
{
    CGFloat newWidth = frameSize.width;
    CGFloat newHeight = ((newWidth / 16) * 9) + 92;

    return (NSSize){newWidth, newHeight};
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Many many thanks, that worked perfectly! :) Seeing as you seem brilliant, want to have a go at my other question as well?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a thing about C#. Glad I could help with this.

Comment: There's an issue: the proposed solution only works when resizing horizontally. If you want to resize your window vertically, changes in height are simply ignored. Any ideas how to make it work so that the window can be resized both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: @Ern: I don't understand your question. The problem is to keep the same aspect ratio. If you are changing the height and width independently, then you lose the aspect ratio.

Comment: The solution is supposed to keep the window's aspect ratio unchanged whenever the user tries to resize the window. I.e., if the user drags (i.e. resizes) the window horizontally, not only width, but also height must change. (Same for vertical resizing.) However, the suggested code snippet only works is the user changes the window's width (then height is updated accordingly). If, however, the user tries resizing the window by changing its height (i.e., drags the bottom side of the window without changing its width), nothing happens: `newHeight` depends on `frameSize.width`, which is unchanged.

Comment: @Ern: Oh, I understand now. I'm still on Snow Leopard, which doesn't have the edge-resize feature of Lion. I think you'll have to look at the window's current/previous size `[(NSWindow *)sender frame].size` to work out whether the resize is vertical or horizontal, then change the other dimension based on that.

Comment: True, Snow Leopard didn't have that. Then everything is OK - I just thought I am missing something obvious (which I was). Thanks!